# I would like to call a method declared from the parent class to the child class in C++

Tags: c++, string, class

I am trying to implement a child class that's derived from the parent class by using inheritance to implement this, but I keep getting this error:

```
/tmp/ccThP1Yc.o: In function `Cat::Cat(double, int)':
Animal.cpp:(.text+0x11a): undefined reference to `vtable for Cat'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using inheritance from the line Cat::Cat(double weight, int age):Animal(name)
The 'name' is the constructor of Animal and I would like to re-use it for Cat, also to use other methods from Animal for Cat.

This is my header file:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #ifndef ANIMAL_H
    #define ANIMAL_H
    
    class Animal
    {
      
      public:
      
        Animal(std::string name);
        std::string get_name();
        virtual double get_weight();
        virtual int get_age();
        
      protected:
        
        std::string animalName;
        
    };
    
    class Cat: public Animal
    {
      
      public:
      
        Cat(double weight, int age);
        
        std::string get_name();
        int get_age();
        double get_weight();
        
      protected:
        
        std::string catType; //type of cat (i.e. Tabby, Siamese)
        
    };
    
    #endif
```

This is my cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Animal.h"
using namespace std;

Animal::Animal(string name)
{
    animalName = name;
};

string Animal::get_name()
{
  
  return animalName;
    
};

double Animal::get_weight()
{
    return 0.0;   
};


int Animal::get_age()
{
    return 0;
}

Cat::Cat(double weight, int age):Animal("Cat")       ////error is here
{
    
};
```

I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: Totally unrelated: In the header, place the includes inside the [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Comment: Also totally unrelated: Functions don't need `;`s

Answer (score 5):

You declared the virtual functions in the derived class

```
class Cat: public Animal
{
  
  public:
  
    Cat(double weight, int age);
    
    std::string get_name();
    int get_age();
    double get_weight();
    //..
```

but forgot to define them.

A declaration of a virtual function in a derived class that has the same signature as a virtual function in the base class means that you have to override its base class definition in the derived class.

Pay attention to that in the class Animal the function should be declared like

```
    virtual double get_weight() const ;
    virtual int get_age() const;
```

and in the class Cat if you are going to override them they should be declared like

```
    double get_weight() const override;
    int get_age() const override;
```

Bear in mind that if you want that the class Animal would be an abstract class you could declare the virtual functions like pure virtual

```
    virtual double get_weight() const = 0;
    virtual int get_age() const = 0;
```

This does not prevent definitions of them in the class Animal though you may leave them undefined.

Note: remove null statements after function definitions like in this case

```
double Animal::get_weight()
{
    return 0.0;   
};
^^^
```

Comment: Alternative: If you want `Animal` to be an [abstract base class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class), make the function pure virtual. Eg: `virtual double get_weight() = 0;`

Comment: @user4581301 She defined the functions in the class Animal.:)

Comment: Not much point to that. `Animal` has nothing useful to return in those functions. I stand by making them pure virtual.